# How to compare tensorflow tensors with Python objects?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to convert string label tensors loaded from tfrec files into numbers for one-hot encoding. The idea is to use a numpy array as a lookup table, and once there's a hit, the index is returned and stored in a tensor.

However, the problem is that tensors cannot be directly compared with python objects. I tried to implement using tf.map_fn to enumerate my batch of labels and tf.cond to make the comparison - which didn't work:

```
def elem_op(t):
    global all_labels
    for idx, lbl in enumerate(all_labels):
        lbl_tensor = tf.constant(lbl.encode())  # tensorflow stores string as bytes, so convert the Python string object to bytes tensor
        ret = tf.cond(tf.equal(lbl_tensor, t), lambda : idx, lambda : -1)
        if ret != -1:  # now this doesn't work because tf.cond returns a tensor
            return ret
    return -1

# labels is a tensor storing a batch of label strings
train_labels = tf.map_fn(fn=elem_op, elems=labels, dtype=tf.int32)
```

The problem is that tf.cond also returns a tensor and cannot be used in a "if" clause. And I wonder what's the way of resolving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention that this routine will be called within a "model_fn" so there is no explicit "session" object, esp. in the elem_op sub-routine, and I cannot use sess.run(ret) or ret.eval(session=sess).

Answer (score 1):

You have to evaluate the tensor in a session in order to obtain it's actual value.

Change you if condition to:

```
if sess.run(ret) != -1:
```

where `sess` is your `tf.Session` instance. For example:

```
sess = tf.Session()
```

Similarly, you may run:

```
sess.run(train_labels)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that there's no explicit session object within model_fn so unfortunately this wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm afraid that the answer to "How to compare tensorflow tensors with Python objects [without a session]?" is "You don't".

Comment: Well that's one way of doing it - pre-process all the string labels into integers before passing them to tensorflow, thus avoiding the tensor v.s. python-obj comparison. But I wonder if there's another way of doing this..?